# Bash: Loop through file and read substring as argument, execute multiple instances

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, lftp

**How it is now**

I currently have a script running under windows that frequently invokes recursive file trees from a list of servers.

I use an AutoIt (job manager) script to execute 30 parallel instances of lftp (still windows), doing this:

```
lftp -e "find .; exit" <serveraddr>
```

The file used as input for the job manager is a plain text file and each line is formatted like this:

```
<serveraddr>|...
```

where "..." is unimportant data. I need to run multiple instances of lftp in order to achieve maximum performance, because single instance performance is determined by the response time of the server.

Each lftp.exe instance pipes its output to a file named

```
<serveraddr>.txt
```

**How it needs to be**

Now I need to port this whole thing over to a linux (Ubuntu, with lftp installed) dedicated server. From my previous, very(!) limited experience with linux, I guess this will be quite simple.

What do I need to write and with what? For example, do I still need a job man script or can this be done in a single script? How do I read  from the file (I guess this will be the easy part), and how do I keep a max. amount of 30 instances running (maybe even with a timeout, because extremely unresponsive servers can clog the queue)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parallel processing

I'd use GNU/parallel. It isn't distributed by default, but can be installed for most Linux distributions from default package repositories. It works like this:

```
parallel echo ::: arg1 arg2
```

will execute `echo arg1` and and `echo arg2` in parallel.

So the most easy approach is to create a script that synchronizes your server in bash/perl/python - whatever suits your fancy - and execute it like this:

`parallel ./script ::: server1 server2`

The script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#$0 holds program name, $1 holds first argument.
#$1 will get passed from GNU/parallel. we save it to a variable.
server="$1"
lftp -e "find .; exit" "$server" >"$server-files.txt"
```

`lftp` seems to be available for Linux as well, so you don't need to change the FTP client.

To run max. 30 instances at a time, pass a `-j30` like this: `parallel -j30 echo ::: 1 2 3`

### Reading the file list

Now how do you transform specification file containing `<server>|...` entries to GNU/parallel arguments? Easy - first, filter the file to contain just host names:

```
sed 's/|.*$//' server-list.txt
```

`sed` is used to replace things using regular expressions, and more. This will strip everything (`.*`) after the first `|` up to the line end (`$`). <sub>(While `|` normally means alternative operator in regular expressions, in sed, it needs to be escaped to work like that, otherwise it means just plain `|`.)</sub>

So now you have list of servers. How to pass them to your script? With `xargs`! `xargs` will put each line as if it was an additional argument to your executable. For example

```
echo -e "1\n2"|xargs echo fixed_argument
```

will run

```
echo fixed_argument 1 2
```

So in your case you should do

```
sed 's/|.*$//' server-list.txt | xargs parallel -j30 ./script :::
```

### Caveats

Be sure not to save the results to the same file in each parallel task, otherwise the file will get corrupt - coreutils are simple and don't implement any locking mechanisms unless you implement them yourself. That's why I redirected the output to `$server-files.txt` rather than `files.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer! I've created a script, `job.sh` with the content you provided. When executing with `sh` it works (example: `sh ./job.sh ftp.microsoft.com`). However, executing the whole thing, `sed s/|.*$//' end_unique.txt | xargs parallel -j30 ./job.sh :::`, just prints `>` and idles. No tasks are being created. Does it matter that end_unique's lines terminate with CRLF?

Comment: I missed apostrophe in the final example. If an apostrophe is missing, bash understands the command you typed isn't yet finished and prompts you to type the rest using `>` prompt. I updated the example that should work.

Comment: Stupid me, should have spotted that. So, now it runs, but xarg doesn't seem to parse the argument the way I want. Executing `sed 's/|.*$//' end_unique.txt | xargs parallel -j30 ./job.sh :::` now just trows an error from batch, which looks like: `/bin/bash: <server>: command not found.`.

Comment: Hmm. Does `sed 's/|.*$//' end_unique.txt` return what you want, meaning, only entries such as `ftp.microsoft.com`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. <server> can be an IP or a hostname and `sed 's/|.*$//' end_unique.txt` gets them all.

Comment: Also, one more question: Does `parallel` wait until all of the 30 instances finished? Previously, I replaced empty slots with new instances when one was finished.

Comment: It tries to maintain 30 processes at the same time.  Try adding `#/bin/sh` at the top of the `job.sh` - it's different to run `sh job.sh` and `./job.sh`; in the latter case Linux needs instruction (= shebang) which executable should be used to run the script.

Comment: Did that, same result. This is how my script looks like: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AzszpwTa). And this is my command: `desktop@***:~$ sed 's/|.*$//' end_unique.txt | xargs parallel -j20 ./job.sh :::`.

Comment: Uhm, I just tested it and it works on my end. Do you have `lftp` installed? Are you sure `./job.sh ftp.microsoft.com` works?

Comment: Yes, I needed to `chmod -x` the script file, but running it works fine. `lftp` is installed, so is `parallel`. Still the same error is displayed, it just prints every single server address in the file as an error.

Comment: Frankly, I believe this deserves separate question. Perhaps you've got different version of GNU/parallel. I'm not sure how can I help you since I can't reproduce the above message...

Comment: OK, i will create a seperate question. Thanks.

Comment: If you remove `xargs` and `:::`, then the behaviour will be the same, no? Since parallel is designed as a drop-in replacement for xargs, you should really very rarely need to use both in the same command.